# Css animation not working only under chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

Duplicate warning, sorry.

I have read couple similar posts, and tried all solutions but none did work.

I have really simple animation that will hide, show and imge.

```
#top_heading .chmurka2{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:257px;
-webkit-animation: top_chmurka2 8s 1s infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: top_chmurka2 8s 1s infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: top_chmurka2 8s 1s infinite alternate;
     -o-animation: top_chmurka2 8s 1s infinite alternate;
        animation: top_chmurka2 8s 1s infinite alternate;

}

@-webkit-keyframes top_chmurka2 { /*chrome and safari*/
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes top_chmurka2{ /*mozilla*/
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes top_chmurka2{ /*before IE 10*/
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes top_chmurka2{ /*IE9+, Opera*/
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes top_chmurka2 { /*standard*/
  0%  { opacity:1; }
  50% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

It works fine, on all major browsers, except Chrome, despite I use -webkit- .
What is going on?
(I also triend using -webkit- inside keyframes rules, but it did not work as well)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, since I don't see anything wrong with it and it works for me.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe sth is wrong with my version of chrome? (Version 37.0.2062.120 m "Up to date" :) )

Comment: Yes, or not -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/nsgNG/124/)

Comment: I created fidle with sth similar: http://jsfiddle.net/cn9369mp/

Comment: Oh, you were faster then me :D. And yout animation is working under my chrome.

Comment: This is really strange, jsfiddle works just fine, but not animation on my page (same code). I made my friend to instal chrome and gavehim url, and it works (my page I mean) under his chrome too :). Thx for help, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently my animation code is fine, but my chrome is not.

Comment: Since "the same" code works for you in a fiddle it's unlikely that Chrome is the problem. I'd rather suspect it has something to do with caching. Try to clear your cache.

Comment: No it was no caching :) I accauly have it disabled while I develop stuff. Still have no idea what only my chrome is giving me troubles